# React, page is refreshing constantly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I was playing around with react for my first time and ran into some issues. I am creating 3 buttons with values and then executing a function when they're clicked that sends a post request and gets back data which is displayed to the user. For some reason, the _postURL function is being executed infinitely even when I dont click on the buttons. Does anyone know why?

```
var Test = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function(){

        return { logs: []};
    },
    _postURL: function(name){
        self = this;
        console.log(name);
        $.post("http://localhost:8080/DatabaseDemo/Display.do", {query: name})
            .done(function(data){
                console.log(data);
                self.setState({logs: data});
        });

    },
    render: function() {
        if(!this.state.logs){
            logs = <p>Choose a log</p>
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <button value="api_log_colo2_mysql2_Jan2015" onClick={this._postURL("api_log_colo2_mysql2_Jan2015")}>Jan2015</button>
                    <button value="api_log_colo2_mysql2_Aug2014" onClick={this._postURL("api_log_colo2_mysql2_Aug2014")}>Aug2014</button>
                    <button value="api_log_colo2_mysql2_Dec2014" onClick={this._postURL("api_log_colo2_mysql2_Dec2014")}>Dec2014</button>
                </form>
                <p>{this.state.logs}</p>
            </div>
        );          
    }
});
```

Comment: The `onClick` attribute expects a function but you are passing `undefined`.

Comment: is this._postURL("api_log_colo2_mysql2_Dec2014") not a valid function?

Comment: You are executing the function, then passing what the function returns, and it returns nothing, so `undefined`. Try `this._postURL.bind(this, 'api_log...')`

Answer (score 2):

The `onClick` attribute expects a function but you are executing the function, which returns `undefined`. You can use `bind`:

```
onClick={this._postURL.bind(this, 'api_log...')}
```

Answer (score 2):

Each of the `onClick` functions that you have defined are being called once the render is called. Once the function is called, it updates the state of the component, which fires the render again. That is why it happens indefinitely. Since jsx is really just javascript, the functions are being executed once they are evaluated. As elclanrs stated, you can use `.bind()` to have your function wait to be called until the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling function in onClick={this._postURL("api_log_colo2_mysql2_Jan2015")}, which is called on render itself before clicking button. In that function setState is used resulting in constant rendering in loop.Try passing function reference only like 
onClick={() => {this._postURL("api_log_colo2_mysql2_Jan2015")}}

Answer (score 1):

I know exactly this problem!
You can solve it by just adding `()=>` to `onClick` function.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the issue of the browser refreshing every time I was using a form and to prevent this you should add the prevent default handle.

```
e.preventDefault();
```

in my case the component was like:

```
import './Meme.css'
import data from './memesData.js'


let Meme=()=>{
    console.log(data)
    let handleClick=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("I was clicked")
    }

    return(
        <div className="meme">
        <form className="form">
        <input className="form--inputs" type="text" placeholder="Top Text" />
        <input className="form--inputs" type="text" placeholder="Bottom Text" />
        <button className="form--button" onClick={handleClick}>Get a new meme image </button>
        </form>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Meme;
```